# How to get form name in google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-apps-script-addon

Method `form.getTitle()` returns only title, which is often empty because people fill name on the top left field and title automatically inherits from name.

Is there a way to get the name of the form without using `DriveApp` since it requires restricted scopes?

Comment: Are you suggesting that if title inherits from name,  title is empty in script, but is displayed in the ui?

Comment: Exactly! `getTitle()` returns empty string until I manually change title

Comment: You might create a issue in the issuetracker because the implied title is not retrieved. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: Found there several of the same issues so Google is likely aware of it

Answer (score 0):

There's already [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147023965) opened in google's Public Issue Tracker which you can +1 in the top menu to try to raise the priority.

#### workaround 1:

Get the form title from Drive, for which you need Drive scopes:

```
  var title = DriveApp.getFileById(form.getId()).getName();
```

For your case in which your using an Add-on, you can avoid having to comply with the [additionals requirements](https://developers.google.com/terms/api-services-user-data-policy#additional-requirements-for-specific-api-scopes) in order to use the [restricted scopes](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/gsuite-scopes#restricted_scopes) like in the example above, by using the [Advance Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) and making a [Files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get) request to get the name from the response, for example:

```
var title = Drive.Files.get(form.getId()).title;
```

#### workaround 2:

Tell the users to change the name of the form directly at the top center of the Google Form.

Comment: I know about these workarounds. Drive scopes are restricted for publishing addon. There is only a way to tell users to change title separately

Comment: It's not just about you knowing, it's about [documenting the knowledge publicly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). In your question you didn't mention it was an add-on. I've updated my answer to target this as well.

Comment: The issue link points to MOMA (Google's Intranet)

Comment: i needed this for slacknotify.app but then realised we cannot create google form with no title am i correct? because i tried removing the title but it is not working